# Como inserir vários arrays em uma tabela MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu recebo via Ajax uma requisição `$_POST` com 5 índices sendo que os últimos 3 são Arrays.

Está mais ou menos assim:

```
   Array
    (
    [c] =>
    [s] => 
    [dt] => 
    [nl] => Array
    (
            [0] => valor1
            [1] => valor2
            [2] => valor3
    )

    [ol] => Array
    (
            [0] => valor1
            [1] => valor2
            [2] => valor3
    )

    [cat] => Array
    (
            [0] => valor1
            [1] => valor2
            [2] => valor3
    )

    [save] => save
    )
```

Os índices "c", "s" e "dt" estão sendo salvos em uma tabela:

```
    primeira tabela
     id  |  campaign_name  |   subject     |  date    
     AI  |  $_POST['c']    |   $_POST['s'] |  $_POST['dt']
```

e caso sejam inseridos, os outros índices ("nl","ol" e "cat") são salvos em outra tabela:

```
     id |  main_url    | new_url       | access_count  |  campaign_FK
     AI | $_POST['ol'] | $_POST['nl']  |    NULL       |  id_primeira_tabela
```

Referenciando o `id` da primeira inserção.
A primeira query roda ok.
Minha dificuldade está em montar a query correta para a segunda inserção.

Já usei foreach, for, tentei inserir uma a uma e depois dar um UPDATE (gambiarra). Pesquisei 
bastante no google também e nenhuma das pesquisas serviram para essa dúvida.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Ja tentou `$_POST['ol[0]']` ?

Comment: Já!
Não dá pra montar uma query única utilizando esse índice já que são 3 arrays para a mesma tabela. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$sts = $pdo->prepare("insert into tabela(campaign_name,subject,date) values(?,?,?)");
$sts->bindValue(1, $_POST['c'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->bindValue(2, $_POST['s'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->bindValue(3, $_POST['dt'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->execute();
$sts->closeCursor();
$sts = null;
//NEW ID GERADO
$pk = $pdo->lastInsertId();
//  
$sts = $pdo->prepare("insert into tabela(main_url,new_url,access_count,campaign_FK) values(?,?,NULL,?)");
$listaOl = $_POST['ol'];
$listaNl = $_POST['nl'];
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($listaOl); $i++){
    $sts->execute(array($listaOl[$i], $listaNl[$i], $pk));  
}
$sts->closeCursor();
$sts = null;
```

No PDO (precisa colocar os dados do banco), e tabela dentro do `$pdo->prepare` precisa trocar para o nome da sua tabela !!!

***Referencia***

- [The PDO class](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php#class.pdo)

Comment: Great Man!!
Eu já estava utilizando o PDO, só não sabia como manipular ele para utlizar dessa forma. Ficou perfeito! Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Se a questão é inserir várias linhas na tabela com uma única query, você pode usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2), (val3, val4);
```

O exemplo acima é para duas linhas, mas você pode adaptá-lo para quantas precisar, e parametrizar a query como sugerido na resposta do Fúlvio.